# ExecuteNonQuery() method fails when running script from task scheduler. No errors when ran manually

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, oledbconnection, oledbcommand, executenonquery

So I implemented a function that logs to a database

```
function write-logDB ($user,$message,$reason,$script,$dbConnection) {
    $sql= "INSERT INTO ScriptLogging(Date_Time,Person,Message,Reason,Script) 
    VALUES (GETDATE(),'$user','$message','$reason','$script')"
    $command = new-object -TypeName System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
    $command.Connection = $dbConnection
    $command.CommandText = $sql
    $command.ExecuteNonQuery()
}
```

This function uses a ALREADY open DB connection to write the log. When running this script with ISE open this script iterates through each user logging the necessary values in the DB.. no problem.

*HOWEVER* if this script is being ran through task scheduler (through a timed event or manually right clicking and clicking run) the script will fail out and I will get the following exception error:

"ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed. at Line Number 655 in CreateStudents - MasterLog.ps1 Function Main ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed. at Line Number 655 in CreateStudents - MasterLog.ps1 Function Main"

This is erroring out on is part of my function for logging. I am not sure why the connection is closed when running through task scheduler.. It does not even iterate through 2 users before errors.

I have confirmed and reconfirmed I am using the same exact account through task manager as I am when running manually. I also confirmed a million times that it is pointing at the right script..

I know you may not have a answer for this but even help troubleshooting or how I should troubleshoot would be appreciated. The only data I am getting back when the script fails to task scheduler is the error code I posted above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the open connection succeed? I have run into double hop issues when trying to do things like this specifically with SQL. (you could do a try/catch and log the connection to a text file to see whats happening)

Comment: Permissions are often an issue for scheduled tasks as well.